# Search and Replace tool for Windows Registry

Tags: windows, gratis, search, portable, windows-registry

Please recommend a gratis Windows tool to perform search and replace operations in the Windows Registry.

I would like to select a Registry key and have the tool perform the search and replace operation on all values stored in that key and its subkeys.

All I need is support for basic ASCII strings for the the search and replace terms.  If the tools supports regular expressions or wildcards, that's great, but not required.

Ideally, the tool will show a preview of all the changes it will make before actually making them, but this is not a requirement.

Open-source is preferred, but not required.

The tool must be portable (no installers, please).

Please specify in your answer which version(s) of Windows your recommendation supports.

Answer (score 5):

### [Registry Finder](https://registry-finder.com/)

- Free
- Portable
- Windows XP-10
- View all search results in a list.
- Undo actions.

Comment: Thank you jsmith! And welcome to Software Recommendations SE!  Can you add a link in your answer to Registry Finder?  I found https://registry-finder.com/.  Is that the one you are recommending? It sounds like it could be perfect. Also, it is gratis (we use that term in this SE to mean "free of financial cost"), which you can add to your answer too, if you like.

Comment: domain seems to offline now

Comment: @mattwilkie working

Comment: @jsmith still not available for me, multiple browsers tried. Downforeveryoneorjustme.com says it's up, so it looks like our firewall is blocking the domain. Fwiw, Google says the site doesn't have unsafe content, https://transparencyreport.google.com/safe-browsing/search?url=https:%2F%2Fregistry-finder.com%2F&hl=en.